# $p$ is prime. Show that $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields

> Let $p$ ∈ $\mathbb N$ be a prime number. Show that $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ contains no zero-divisors except $0$, hence ($\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$)$^∗$ = {$1, 2, . . . , p − 1$}, and $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is a field. Where ($\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$)$^∗$ is the set of units.

My attempt:

Suppose $ab=0$ for $b\ne 0$. Then $ab\equiv 0\mod p$ and so $p$ divides the product $ab$. Since $p$ is a prime, it follows that $p$ divides a factor. So $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. But $b\ne 0$ and so $p\mid a$, i.e., $a\equiv 0\mod p$, i.e., $a=0$ in ${\Bbb Z}_p$.

Now, for the "hence ($\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$)$^∗$ = {$1, 2, . . . , p − 1$}" part, I know that $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$ = {$0,1,2,...,p-1$} and I already proved in a previous part of this problem that an element in a ring is either a zero-divisor or a unit. And thus, since $0$ is the zero-divisor, then all the other elements of $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$ are units, therefore ($\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$)$^∗$ = {$1, 2, . . . , p − 1$}. Is this correct?

For the "$\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is field" part, I know that a field is a commutative ring, so all I have to do here is to show that $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is commutative? And if so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

''Now, for the "hence (Z/pZ)∗ = {1,2,...,p−1}" part, I know that Z/pZ = {0,1,2,...,p−1} and I already proved in a previous part of this problem that an element in a ring is either a zero-divisor or a unit. And thus, since 0 is the zero-divisor, then all the other elements of Z/pZ are units, therefore (Z/pZ)∗ = {1,2,...,p−1}. Is this correct?''

In the previous part you proved that the ring contains no zero divisors. By definition, zero is not a zero divisor.

But this does not imply that the ring is a field, i.e., all nonzero divisors are units. For instance, the ring of integers contains no zero divisors, but only $\pm 1$ are units.

To show that ${\Bbb Z}_p$ is a field, it is clear from the construction that it is a commutative quotient ring with elements $0,1,\ldots,p-1$.

Take a nonzero element $a$. Then $\gcd(a,p)=1$ and so by Bezout's theorem,

$ra+sp=1$

for some integers $r,s$. Thus $ra\equiv 1\mod p$, i.e., $ra=1$ in ${\Bbb Z}_p$. Thus $a$ is invertible with inverse $a^{-1}=r$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that not all commutative rings are fields; a field is a commutative **division** ring, which means that there are no zero divisors (as shown in the first part). So the division ring part is done and we are left with commutativity. Now, $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is constructed as the integers modulo $p$, so the fact that it is commutative follows simply fro the fact that $\mathbb Z$ is commutative.

Answer (score 1):

You could prove that $\mathbb Z /p\mathbb Z$ is commutative with a direct proof. However it’s interesting to understand this more general result: [Quotient Ring of Commutative Ring is Commutative](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_Ring_of_Commutative_Ring_is_Commutative) and to apply it to your special case noting that $\mathbb Z$ is a commutative ring.

It is true that units are non zero divisors here as we’re considering a finite ring. This is not true in general.

Answer (score 0):

This answer only deals with commutativity.

For $n,m\in\mathbb Z$ on base of commutativity of multiplication in $\mathbb Z$ we find by applying definition of multiplication in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$: $$(n+p\mathbb Z)(m+p\mathbb Z):=nm+p\mathbb Z=mn+p\mathbb Z=(m+p\mathbb Z)(n+p\mathbb Z)$$

Comment: What does this tell me?

Comment: I wrongly did it with addition (sorry), but it should be multiplication of course. Now - after repairing it -  it does concern multiplication and it tells you that the multiplication in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is commutative.

Answer (score 0):

p is prime implies $p\mathbb{Z}$ is maximal ideal (as well as prime) of $\mathbb{Z} $
Then quotient ring is a field.